# ACERA VS STX RC

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur, upgrades

Hi everyone i have two rear derailleur barely used one Shimano Acera and one Shimano STX who has the best performace ? The main terrain for my bicycle will be off road downhill . I also have the front derailleur Shimano STX RC , gears Shimano STX RC hubs (front and rear) Shimano STC RC and Casette is a 8speed Shimano but don't know what model

Answer (score 2):

Historically STX-RC was higher in the series than Acera.
If they are from the same year - than STX-RC would be the "better performing".
If they are from different years - than Shimano have a habit of trickling down technology from one series to another over subsequent years - so harder to say.

Comment: IIRC, it was essentially Deore level gear